# CakePHP 3, how to use different Datasource based on the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

Tags: php, cakephp, server

I have 2 Datasources defined in the app.php.

```
'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [...
        'test' => [...
```

I would like to ask how can i use different datasource during the init of the app using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` or any CakePHP method?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

In your config/app.php file create your new datasource(s) using your server names.

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [...
    'test' => [...
    'YOUR_SERVER_NAME_HERE' => [...
    'YOUR_SERVER_NAME2_HERE' => [...
```

Then in config/bootstrap.php add

```
ConnectionManager::alias('default', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```

From then on any time the app tries to access the default connection it'll instead be routed to the new connection you've added.

If you're not looking to add new datasources but instead have a scenario where one server is your test server in your config/bootstrap.php add a switch to check your $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] and then in your case add the ConnectionManager::alias('default', 'test or whatever datasource you want');